# Fire and forget task in asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

When using Python's `asyncio` library, how can I fire off a task and then not care about its completion?

### Example

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def f():
    yield From(asyncio.sleep(1))
    print("world!")

@asyncio.coroutine
def g():
    desired_operation(f())
    print("Hello, ")
    yield From(asyncio.sleep(2))

>>> loop.run_until_complete(g())
'Hello, world!'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) (or `asyncio.async` if your version of `trollius`/`asyncio` is too old to have `ensure_future`):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import trollius as asyncio
from trollius import From

@asyncio.coroutine
def f():
    yield From(asyncio.sleep(1))
    print("world!")

@asyncio.coroutine
def g():
    asyncio.ensure_future(f())
    print("Hello, ", end='')
    yield From(asyncio.sleep(2))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(g())
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
```